# IMAP "connects" to folder that does not exist?

Tags: php, imap

**What I want to do**

I want to check whether a folder in my imap inbox exists

**What I do**

```
if (imap_open("{" . $mbUrl . "}/" . $folder, $mbUsername, $mbPassword)) {
    echo $folder . " exists";
} else {
   echo $folder . " does not exist";
}
```

**What happens**

`$folder` always exists, no matter if it really does not on the server. Is there another way to check for a folder?

*Side Note*

I read [somewhere](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imap-open.php#115637) that subfolders need a dot as a seperator. Whether or not this is true, it does not matter.

Comment: php procedural functions don't throw exceptions, ever. they generally return a boolean false on failure.

Comment: Updated, same thing happens